# Jekyll markdown titles to links

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll for my static blog. I write the posts using Markdown.

**The problem I have is that Jekyll does not create the links associated with the titles**. And I would try to do that without using Javascript.

Here is an example, let's call this page `mysite.com/page`

```
# My title

bla bla bla
```

I would like Jekyll to include a link to `mysite.com/page/#my-title` or `mysite.com/page#my-title` as both work typing them by hand. **Just like it is possible on any Github readme (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#try-your-first-tensorflow-program) for instance)**

I am using Kramdown:

```
markdown:      kramdown
markdown_ext:  markdown,mkd,mkdn,md
textile_ext:   textile
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
excerpt_separator: "<!-- more -->"
```

Comment: Are you using kramdown? If you are using kramdown they will be generated automatically.

Comment: yes, but still does not generate the anchor links..

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved it thanks to @streetturtle and the issue on Github.

#### Anchor JS

I'm using the [Anchor JS](https://www.bryanbraun.com/anchorjs/) script, and add it to my html templates

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/anchor-js/3.2.0/anchor.min.js"></script>
```

#### Usage

In a new script I simply add the following lines :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  anchors.add('article section h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
  anchors.options.placement = 'left';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want to have is called anchor links. Kramdown should support them by default (check in `_config.xml` if it's turned on). Otherwise there is an [issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2690) on jekyll github page, where you can find more details.